# How to modify pretrained model input shape in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

When I no use pretrained model and input channel is 8 ,its can run

but acc very low and confusion_matrix show predict result centralized at one classe(the class have 90 image, another classes about 20~50 image, total 270 image)

```
base = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights=None,input_shape=[img_height,img_width,8])
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base,
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax') 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax') 
    ])
    ....
```

But when I use pretrained model I got error message

```
base = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=[img_height,img_width,8])
```

```
ValueError
The input must have 3 channels; got `input_shape=[512, 512, 8]`
  File "C:\Labbb\inceptionResnetV2\InceptionResnetV2_1.py", line 110, in <module>
    base = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=[img_height,img_width,8]) 
ValueError: The input must have 3 channels; got `input_shape=[512, 512, 8]`
```

How to modify pretrained model input shape?

Comment: You cannot, pretrained weights make assumption about the number of channels, so this only works on RGB images.

Comment: Which images do have 8 channels?

Comment: @user2586955 I merge lot of GLCM image to a 8-channel npy file

Comment: If you want to use 8-channels then you need to fit your custom model from scratch. I using transfer learning is critical to you then you could separate the 8 channels into 3 groups of 3-channels (just repeat last channel to have 9), and then use three pertained models for each group, then apply features late fusion.